# Set Background Color to RGB UIColor ButtonTypeRoundedRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicolor

I've been looking all over the place for the past half hour trying to find a way to create a button with round corners that can have a custom rgb background...

This is what I have currently, but clearly it doesn't work:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TimesCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //[cell sizeToFit];


    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(customActionPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@"Custom Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 50);

    int r = 255-1;
    int g = 255-180;
    int b = 7-1;

    NSLog(@"%i", 180+(int)((g/5)*(indexPath.row+1)));

    UIColor *thisColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1+(int)((r/5)*(indexPath.row+1)) green:180+(int)((g/5)*(indexPath.row+1)) blue:1+(int)((b/5)*(indexPath.row+1)) alpha:1];

    button.backgroundColor = thisColor;
    button.clipsToBounds = YES;
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 15;


    [cell addSubview:button];

    return cell;
}
```

I've seen a bunch of stuff about how you can't set the background color on a roundedRect and how to fix it but I need to be able to dynamically generate the color as you can see in the code...

Currently it just doesn't have a background color for the buttons. Interestingly, if I use `[UIColor colorColor]` it works just fine, it's just the RGB that throws it off.

How can I go about this in my situation specifically?

Comment: You should describe what it does wrong...

Comment: you can take button as a UIButtonTypeCustom

Comment: @shalini I tried to do this, but changing the buttonWithType to UIButtonTypeCustom made no buttons appear at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create your colour the components each need to be in the range 0 to 1. Yours look to be up to 255 so you need to divide them all by 255.0 (apart from the alpha which you have correct).

Answer (score 12):

**You need to do like this**
First take RGB codes value from **Color Palette** from this you will get three different code for **red , green and blue** then to apply the color to your **Control**

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customButton setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 100, 200, 40)];

[customButton setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:50/255.0f blue:60/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

[customButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:
 UIControlStateHighlighted];
[customButton setTitle:@"Custom Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:customButton];
```

**here in code 255,50,60 is a RGB code Value**

Answer (score 3):

**This will surely work**

```
UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:f];
button.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
button.layer.borderWidth = 1;
button.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
button.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: '.CGColor' in "[UIColor grayColor].CGColor" solved my issue, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

No sure about your RGB value but divide by 255

```
UIColor *thisColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(1+(int)((r/5)*(indexPath.row+1))/255) green:(180+(int)((g/5)*(indexPath.row+1))/255) blue:(1+(int)((b/5)*(indexPath.row+1))/255) alpha:1];
```

Comment: someone else already said this. You need to check your order of operations though

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this

```
UIColor *thisColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(1+(int)((r/5)*(indexPath.row+1)))/225.f green:(180+(int)((g/5)*(indexPath.row+1)))/255.f blue:(1+(int)((b/5)*(indexPath.row+1)))/255.f alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Swift solution ripped off from one of these previous answers.
For avant-garde devs :P

```
import Foundation

struct ColorUtils {
    static func hexToUIColor (hex: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIColor {
        var rgbValue: UInt32 = 0
        var scanner = NSScanner(string: hex)
        scanner.scanLocation = 1
        scanner.scanHexInt(&rgbValue)
        let red = (CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)) / 255.0
        let green = (CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF)) / 255.0
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    } 
}

// Use:
// ColorUtils.hexToUIColor("#FF0000") // you can optionally add alpha as second arg
```